# Basic questions about Contact metric structure

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, symplectic-geometry, contact-geometry

Let $(M,\xi)$ be a coorientable contact $(2n+1)$-manifold with $\alpha$ and $R$ as contact form and Reeb vector field, respectively.
A contact metric structure on $(M,\xi)$ is a pair $(J,g)$ where $J$ is a (1,1)-tensor satisfying
$$J^2=-Id+\alpha\otimes R,$$
and $g$ is a metric satisfying $d\alpha(-,-)=g(J-,-)$ and $g(-,-)=g(J-,J-)+\alpha^2(-,-)$.

I have a couple of probably simple questions about this definition:

1. What is the area form of $g$? is it true that it is simply $\alpha\wedge(d\alpha)^n$ and that $\star\alpha=(d\alpha)^n$ for the hodge star operator?
2. Can we extend $J$ to forms? In turn, what is its relation with $\star$, i.e. $[J,\star]$=?

If it makes it easier, I'm mostly interested in the 3-dimensional case, where $J$ on $\xi$ is the rotation by $\pi/2$ in the positive direction.

Comment: The area form of $g$ is given by $\alpha \wedge (d\alpha)^n$ (consider orthonormal bases of the form $\{R,e_1,Je_1,\ldots,e_n,Je_n\}$.) This should be helpuf to find out what is $\star\alpha$

Comment: I have seen in most papers that $\xi$ is the Reeb vector field and no new notation $R$ is needed.